# Getting zero instead of Blank value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Why below code gives me 0 or zero instead of blank value or blank row
in column ValueA.

How can I change it to blank value?

```
select ValueA = case when ValueB = 'No' then ValueA
                     when ValueB = 'Yes' then ''
                     else ''
                     end
From Table
```

or

if I use `ValueB = 'Yes' then CAST(NULL AS varchar(25))`  gives me Null 
and I want blank where it is Null, but when I try to convert to blank
I get zero.  Why?

How can I get blank?

Comment: What type is the column "ValueA"?

Comment: You want blank instead of null...why?  Are you consuming the data in asp.net, etc. (or otherwise, consuming it with something that doesn't handle null values the way you'd like)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ValueA is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because valueA is a number, and it can't contain a "blank row". It's either going to be 0 or NULL. If you want blanks, you need to use varchar or an equivalent character field.

Answer (score 1):

ValueA must be a numeric data type. Also, your `WHEN 'Yes'` and `ELSE` are redundant. Try:

```
SELECT ValueA = CASE ValueB 
       WHEN 'No'  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), ValueA)
       ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.[Table];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    case when ValueB = 'No' then Cast(ValueA as VarChar(10))
         when ValueB = 'Yes' then '' 
         else '' 
         end as ValueA
    From Table
```